# A question referring equites and beta

Tags: equities

Let's say stock A has a beta of 1.32 and stock B has a beta of .8.

Is it okay to say that, stock A moves 32% more than the market?

And Stock B moves 20% less than the market?

Comment: I everyday speech people often do say that, and I think it is fine.  Keep in mind though that the mathematical relationship is between *excess returns* $R_S-R_f$ and $R_M-R_f$ not strictly speaking between the returns $R_S$ and $R_M$. But $R_f$ the risk free rate per day is very small so practically almost zero. To say "Stock B moves 20% less than the market on an excess return basis" seems unnecessarily pedantic.

Comment: This refers to the movement of these stocks that are explained by the movement of the market as a whole. But additionally a stock can move in idiosyncratic ways not attributable to market movement.

Comment: ...exactly. So you could say "the market movement (or systematic movement) of Stock B is 20% less than the market"